# positioning labels on canvas

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having some issues placing labels on a canvas such that they're stacked perfectly below each other (ultimately I want to create a scrollable table). Here are my problems:

I don't really understand what is meant with 'height' or 'width' when creating a label. Because if I choose height = 1 and width =2. Shouldn't the label be twice as long as?

-Why are the labels not stacked correctly? It seems I should use a much larger value for the create_window method.

```
    import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width = 600, height = 300)
canvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

label1 = tk.Label(canvas, text = 'first label 1', width = 20, height = 1, relief = 'solid')
label1.pack()
label2 = tk.Label(canvas, text = 'second label 2', width = 20, height = 1, relief = 'solid')

canvas.create_window(300, 150, window = label1)
canvas.create_window(300, 150 + label1['height'], window = label2)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `label1.winfo_reqheight()` instead of `label1['height']`:

```
canvas.create_window(300, 150+label1.winfo_reqheight(), window = label2)
```

Also you do not need to call `label1.pack()` as you are putting the label inside `Canvas`.

Answer (score 0):

You could pack your labels in a `tk.Frame`, to align them as you need, then position the frame on the canvas:

Maybe like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width = 600, height = 300)
canvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

frame = tk.Frame(canvas)
label1 = tk.Label(frame, text='first label 1', relief='solid')
label1.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
label2 = tk.Label(frame, text='second label 2', relief='solid')
label2.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

canvas.create_window(300, 150, window=frame)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Question 1:

`-I don't really understand what is meant with 'height' or 'width' when creating a label. Because if I choose height = 1 and width =2. Shouldn't the label be twice as long as?`

No, these numbers are not a use of multiplication, But how many more pixels wider or longer you want it to be.

### Question 2:

`-Why are the labels not stacked correctly? It seems I should use a much larger value for the create_window method.`

You could use [`.place`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm) or [`.grid`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) method instead of `.pack`.